# Naive question about the tensor product of R-modules

Tags: modules, tensor-products

Let $R$ Be a commutative unitary ring and $M,N$ two $R$-module.
Consider the free $R$-module $R^{\bigoplus M \times N}=\{\sum_{(m,n)\in M \times N} r_{(m,n)}e_{(m,n)} \: \vert \: r_{(m,n)} \in R \: \text{and finitely many} \: r_{(m, n)} \: \text{are non-zero}\}$.

For all $(m,n) \in M \times N$, denote by $e_{(m,n)}$ the map which takes value $1$ on $(m,n)$ and $0$ on any other element of $M \times N$.
Then the set of elements $\{e_{(m,n)}, \: m \in M, n \in N\}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of $R^{\bigoplus M \times N}$ and has cardinal $\vert M \times N \vert$.

At last, write $S$ for the submodule of $R^{\bigoplus M \times N}$ generated by the elements $e_{(m+m’,n)}-e_{(m,n)}-e_{(m’,n)}; \: e_{(m, n+n’)}-e_{(m,n)}-e_{(m,n’)}; \: e_{(rm,n)}-e_{(m,rn)}, \: \text{for all} \: m,m’ \in M,\: n,n’ \in N, r \in R$.

We then have the following balanced map B

\begin{equation}
B:\: M \times N \xrightarrow{p_1} R^{\bigoplus M \times N} \xrightarrow{p_2} R^{\bigoplus M \times N}/S=M \otimes_R N.
\end{equation}

So $p_1$ takes $(m,n)$ to $e_{(m,n)} \in R^{\bigoplus M \times N}$ and the the canonical surjection $p_2$ takes $e_{(m,n)}$ to $e_{(m,n)}+S$: it’s coset in $M \otimes_R N$.

My question is about the canonical injection $p_1: M \times N \longrightarrow R^{\bigoplus M \times N}$ such that $p_1((m,n))=e_{(m,n)}$.
It’s a very naive question and ONCE AGAIN it’s about the tensor product but a few things remain unclear to me.

In every proof about the existence of the tensor product, the $p_1$ takes values in the free-module $R^{\bigoplus M \times N}$ but this application only maps the element $(m,n) \in M \times N$ to an element of its $\mathbb{Z}$-basis (i.e. the map $e_{(m,n)}$ that takes value $1$ on $(m,n)$ and $0$ on any other element of $M \times N$).

Am I right if I say that the only linear combination that appears in the image of $p_1$ is $1.e_{(m,n)}=e_{(m,n)}$ for each $(m,n) \in M \times N$ ?
In other words, is it true that, except for $(m,n)$, there is no other element of $M \times N$ « involved » in $p_1((m,n))$ ?
The thing that « disturbs » me is that we defined a very big set (the free-module $R^{\bigoplus M \times N}$ whose elements are formal finite sums indexed by the set $M \times N$) but we only use a very little part of it !

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

We actually use the whole set (its given quotient, exactly) for this construction to properly arrive to the tensor product $M\otimes_RN$.

Its elements are not only the images of $(m,n)$ under $B=p_2\circ p_1$, but, importantly, also formal sums and formal scalar ($R$-) multiples, subject to the identities that the submodule $S$ expresses,  making $B$ a balanced map, i.e. forcing
$$B(m+m',\,n)=B(m,n)+B(m',n)\\
B(m,\,n+n')=B(m,n)+B(m,n')\\
B(m,\,rn)=r\,B(m,n)=B(rm,\,n)$$
to hold in the quotient.

But, in general, the formal sum $B(m,n)+B(m',n')$ is not in the range of $B$ for distinct $m,m',\,n,n'$.